# printing and scanning files in c

Tags: c, file, fgets, scanf

I'm writing a program in c with a file of names and numbers. the user inputs a number and then it should print out the name beside it. the file looks something like this...

```
154 Sam
245 Jane
345 Joe
```

Im not sure how to only print certain words from the file after matching the input from the user, but i do know when i use fgets and fscanf it printd the whole file

so far i have

```
FILE *pf;
pf = fopen("C:\\Sample.text", "a+");
char str[200];
char input2[10];
printf("\nPlease enter a number:");
scanf("%s", &input2);`

while(!feof(pf))
{
    fscanf(pf,"%s/n",str);

    if (strcmp(str,input2)==0)
    {
        printf("The First name is %s\n",fgets(str,10,pf));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to break up a line into parts so you can treat them individually, but since you're already using `scanf` and `fscanf` you might want to consider `sscanf`. Suppose you've read a whole line from the file into `str`, and the line contains both a number and a name:

```
sscanf(str, "%s %s", number_str, name_str);
```

would read the first word on the line into `number_str` and the second word on the line into `name_str`.